# Prove that $EF'$ passes through the circumcenter of $\triangle E'M'N'$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

> $F$ is a point outside $\square ABCD$ such that $\widehat{CFD} = 135^\circ$. $FF' \perp CD$ at $F'$. $AC \cap BD = \{E\}$. $AF \cap BD = \{M\}, AF \cap CD = \{M'\}$ and $BF \cap AC = {N}, BF \cap DC = \{N'\}$. $MC \cap ND = \{E'\}$.
>
> Prove that $EF'$ passes through the circumcenter of $\triangle E'M'N'$.

When I first saw the problem, I couldn't believe my eyes. It's the hardest problem I have ever encountered.

Comment: **This question is missing context or other details**: Please provide additional [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since $\angle CFD = {3\pi \over 4}$, $BCFD$ is cyclic.

Of course, $ABCFD$ is inscribed in a circle with centre $E$.

Now suppose that $DG$ intersects $\bigcirc E$ at M (other than $D$).

So $\angle CDG = \angle CBG(\text{symmetric}) = \angle CDF$.

Similarly, $\angle KCD = \angle FCD$.

Therefore, $\triangle CKD \simeq \triangle CFD$, and these two triangles are symmetric about $CD$.

Second, consider that

$${CI \over ID} = {CF \cdot \sin \angle CFI \over DF \cdot \sin \angle IFD} = {CF \cdot 1 \over DF \cdot {1 \over \sqrt 2}} = {CF \over DF} \cdot \sqrt 2$$

and $${CG \over GE} = {CD \cdot \sin \angle CDG \over DE \cdot \sin \angle EDG} = \sqrt 2 \cdot {\sin \angle CDK \over \sin \angle KCL} = {CK \over KD} \cdot \sqrt 2 \:(\angle EDG = \angle DBF = \angle DCF)$$

$\implies {CI\over ID} = {CG\over GE}$, therefore $\triangle CGI$ is an isosceles right triangle, and so is $\triangle HJD$.

Denote the intersect of $CI$ and $HJ$ as O.

It is clear that $\angle HOI = {\pi \over 2}$, $\angle HKI = \angle HFI = {\pi \over 4}$, and $HO=OI$.

So $O$ is the circumcentre of $\triangle KHI$.

The last important thing to note is that$${LH \over HC} = {KL \cdot \sin \angle LKH \over KC \cdot \sin \angle CKH} = KL \cdot \sqrt 2 \cdot {\sin \angle LDK \over CK}$$

$$(\angle HKD = \angle HFD = {\pi \over 2} = \angle KLD,\text{ so }\angle HKL = \angle KDL)$$

$${LI \over ID} = {KL \cdot \sin \angle LKI \over KD \cdot \sin \angle DKI} = KL \cdot \sqrt 2 \cdot {\sin\angle KCL \over KD}$$

And ${KC \over \sin \angle KDC} = {KD \over \sin \angle KCD} \implies {HL \over HC} = {LI \over ID}$.

Now since $\triangle OHI \sim \triangle ECD$. It is easy to show that $\triangle HLO \sim \triangle CLE$.

$\implies \angle CLO = \angle CLE$. Now $L,O,E$ are collinear.[image]

Comment: There are some other interesting facts I am able to prove as I proceed, so there are a few unnecessary points in the figure.

Comment: Oh, because this is the second task that I had to do. The first one was: Prove that $$\dfrac{E'M}{FM} + \dfrac{E'N}{FN} + \dfrac{M'N'}{CD} = 1$$.

Comment: @LêThànhĐạt I think that can also be proved using some not-so-complacitaed angle chasing.

Comment: Well, I solved that.